# disable a menu permenantly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I would like to be able to disable a menu item after it is chosen. That is, the menu item is available only at the first time it is set. Then onwards it should be completely disabled. How can I do this?

I tried the following:

```
  MenuItem mi=menu.findItem(R.id.item1));
```

And used this code to disable it after "firstrun"

```
 mi.setEnabled(false);
```

However, once I force stop the App and go back to it again. The menu item is enabled.
How can I prevent this and disable it permenanly?

Thanks.

Comment: Clue - sharedPreferences.  Google is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to persist your data somewhere. In this case, I'd suggest using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) which is the preferred way to store simple booleans and other small data, each with a specific key. In your case, once the user has clicked on the menu item, call

```
// Where this is a Context such as your Activity
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(this);
sp.edit().putBoolean("MENU_CLICK", true).apply();
// Use commit() in place of apply() if you support pre-Gingerbread devices
```

Then in your `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, retrieve the shared preference by using

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(this);
// default false to show on first run
final boolean haveClickedMenu = sp.getBoolean("MENU_CLICK", false);
mi.setEnabled(!haveClickedMenu);
```